# iOS - UIKeyboardWillShowNotification called multiple Times when lock screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

I am creating a notification on viewdidload **UIKeyboardWillShowNotification** and removing it on **viewwilldisappear**.

When the keyboard appear on screen and its notification is called once as expected, I locked the screen. The notification is called **4** times and creating undesired functionality.

Why the notification being called? how can i prevent from this scenario?

I am adding Observer for notification in viewdidload in this manner

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

**EDIT:**
Same results if i send the app to background instead of lock screen.

Answer (score 2):

that same thing was happend with me

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                               object:nil];
```

i was presenting a view controller on button click. every time i present Viewcontroller viewdidload get called it add the addObserver. so the method get called multiple time.

Comment: In my case it is being called just once not multiple time

Comment: @Hassy when app goes background UIKeyboardWillShowNotification fire multiple time . it may be os issue.

Comment: Yes most probably it is OS issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your case Notification calls multiple times that shows the addObserver calls multiple time or you are not removing observer once its usage is done.

Simply follow this things :

- As you mentioned you are removing observer in `viewwilldisappear` method. So try to debug & see if it gets called. If this method not getting called try to remove it in `viewDidUnload` method.
- If still you are not able to remove the observer than just simply put remove observer code before the line of add observer. That's it. It will work for sure.

**Note :**

- Solution i have suggested to you is already tried & tested & works fine on my end.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Surely the things you said will work. But the thing is my adding Observer for keyboard Notification is fired once in viewdidload and never being initialized again. viewwilldisappear dont get called on sending app to background neither view did load. This has to be issue at Apple. I will mark your answer correct if i dont get any more responses over the exact issue.

Comment: @ghazi_jaffary i suggest you to debug & see which viewcontroller delegate method calls. Like if viewDidUnload may call in your case

Comment: @ghazi_jaffary are you presenting the viewcontroller where you addObserver ?

Comment: Yeah it is being pushed using navigationalcontroller

Comment: @Mack none of UIViewController delegates get called. Viewwilldisappear and unload. the app is going into background but viewcontroller isnt going anywhere it is still in memory as active viewcontroller.